# Why doesn't this work for the production APNS gateway?

Tags: c#, ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to figure out why the following code works for the sandbox APNS gateway but not the production one.

```
public byte[] ToByteArray(string str)
{
    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
    return enc.GetBytes(str);
}

public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(Object sender, 
                                                X509Certificate certificate, 
                                                X509Chain chain,
                                                SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
   return true; // yah, I'm sure.
}

public void sendMessage()
{
    var debugApp = false;
    int port = 2195;
    String hostname = "gateway.push.apple.com";
    if (debugApp)
    {
        hostname = "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com";
    }
    //load certificate
    string certificatePath = @"C:\APNsPush\ABC_Prod_Cert.p12";
    if (debugApp)
    {
        certificatePath = @"C:\APNsPush\ABC_Dev_Cert.p12";
    }
    string certificatePassword = "";
    X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = 
        new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, certificatePassword);
    X509Certificate2Collection certificatesCollection = 
        new X509Certificate2Collection(clientCertificate);

    TcpClient client = new TcpClient(hostname, port);
    SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(
                   client.GetStream(),
                   false,
                   new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate),
                   null
                   );

    try
    {
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, 
                                        certificatesCollection,
                                        SslProtocols.Tls, 
                                        true);
    }
    catch (AuthenticationException ex)
    {
        client.Close();
        return;
    }

    // Encode a test message into a byte array.
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);
    writer.Write((byte)0);  //The command
    writer.Write((byte)0);  //The first byte of the deviceId 1st (big-endian first byte)
    writer.Write((byte)32); //The deviceId length (big-endian 2nd byte)


    String deviceId = "1c40118b69624a6eec7cf74d353d3600b73e062a25c00d3ee5c462086eae9e97";
    writer.Write(ToByteArray(deviceId.ToUpper()));

    if (debugApp)
    {
        deviceId = "d97fb8bf277471494a0d11d0a89a6866342bdd4aca4acb1edbd3cd6308f7a9f6";
        writer.Write(ToByteArray(deviceId.ToUpper()));
    }

    String payload = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Hello World\",\"badge\":1}}";

    writer.Write((byte)0); //First byte of payload length; (big-endian 1st byte)
    writer.Write((byte)payload.Length);     //payload length (big-endian 2nd byte)

    byte[] b1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
    writer.Write(b1);
    writer.Flush();

    byte[] array = memoryStream.ToArray();
    sslStream.Write(array);
    sslStream.Flush();

    // Close the client connection.
    client.Close();
}
```

If I flip `debugApp` from `false` to `true`, and compile the related app with the Development certificate, and then trigger `sendMessage` I get a lovely "Hello World" notification popping up in my app.

If I flip `debugApp` from back to `false`, and recompile the related app with the Distribution certificate (release as a Beta and download with TestFlight), and then trigger `sendMessage` I get a no notification showing up in my app.

I'm able to telnet to the gateway

```
telnet gateway.push.apple.com 2195
```

so I'm reasonably sure I'm not being blocked by a firewall.

**[start edit]**
I slapped together a little PushSharp application, and I can send messages to my app that way. That confirms that it's not a firewall issue on my workstation.

However, for reasons I'm not going to go into, the original application can't use PushSharp.
**[end edit]**

I even when as far as generating a `pem` file from the production `p12` going to this site http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info/ and sending a message with the Production. The message did make it though to my app compiled with the Distribution certificate. So I'm confident that the `p12` file is correct.

(yes, I recognise I should probably regenerate the `p12`, since it's now effectively compromised by using that other site)

What have I missed?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I know there is some sort of feedback service with the apns gateway. Did you try to get this feedback? Or to use a library like pushsharp which does this for you and raises exceptions on errors?

Comment: I've done a quick test using PushSharp (and the same certificates) and I do get a message through to my Distribution app. However, for "reasons" I can't use PushSharp.

Comment: I'm also in the process of experimenting with feedback.push.apple.com; however, I haven't got it to work yet with the feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com so any errors / exceptions I get aren't much use to me.

Comment: you can try using [pushtry.com][1]


  [1]: http://www.pushtry.com/

Comment: I've already tried it...  the certificates, etc. are all good.